# Facing 401 problem for youtube api for get method

Tags: api, youtube

I'm trying to get list of all the youtube channel, but I'm facing some problem. I didn't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm sending request something like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=AIzaSyASLgZm6GzeRzIhnEW8SAvuhiwerDSGDaeweBg&part=snippets
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provide one of these parameters in the request `forUsername` or `mySubscribers` or `managedByMe` or `categoryId` or `idParam` or  `id` or `mine` along with `part`.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=test&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

the `part` parameter specifies only channel resource properties like these

```
auditDetails,
brandingSettings,
contentDetails,
contentOwnerDetails,
id,
invideoPromotion,
localizations,
snippet,
statistics,
status,
topicDetails
```

so use `snippet` instead of `snippets`, that might also be a reason why the API call fails

Comment: can i use any text for forUsername

Comment: Set the `forUsername` parameter to a YouTube username to retrieve information for the channel associated with that username. This example sets the `forUsername` parameter value to `Google` to retrieve information for Google's official YouTube channel.